# Getting column names from SysHeader32 control in another process

Tags: c++, winapi, interprocess, common-controls

I am making a program (program1) that will read the name of the columns of a header (SysHeader32) that is located in a report-style List (SysListView32) in another program (program2).

So basically I want my program to go into another program and read what the title name is for all the headers (SysHeader32) that I find. Since the program has a lot of different lists and headers for each list, I decided to use the `EnumChildWindows` function with an `EnumChildProc` callback function to look through all the handles of the child window. With those handles I use `GetClassName()` to see what the class name is and when I see it is a SysHeader32, I know I found a header that can contain various title names... but I have no idea what code I can use to get the text from these various titles, nor do I know how to identify each title...

Here is the code I have so far that will find the handle for each SysHeader32 header found:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc (HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
  char myBuffer [100];//buffer that will get the class name
  GetClassName(hWnd, myBuffer, 100);
  string myString (myBuffer);//converting myBuffer into a readable string

  if (myString == "SysHeader32")
  {
    ///here is where I am currently lost
    ///I just don't know how to get the text from the different titles/items
    ///in the header found
  }
}
```

Question 1:: How do I check how many different titles / items there are in the header?

Question 2:: How do I get the text for each of the titles / items found in the header?

Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not easily possible when accessing a window created by another program, because the system doesn't do the necessary window message marshalling of pointers. You would need to do this from a shared DLL file (create some system-wide Windows Hook in it to load it into other processes) or using other hacks like inter-process memory access.

---

If accessing a SysHeader32 window in the same program, it would be simple as this:

1. Send message [`HDM_GETITEMCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775337.aspx), it returns the number of items.
2. Send message [`HDM_GETITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775335.aspx) with `wParam` set to the index of the item to retrieve and `lParam` set to a pointer to appropriately set `HDITEM` structure. Particularly set `mask` to `HDI_TEXT` and prepare a buffer for `pszText` and set its length in to `cchTextMax`.

Example:

```
int count = SendMessage(hWnd, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
std::cout << "There are " << count << " items.\n";

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  TCHAR name[260];
  HDITEM hdi;
  hdi.mask = HDI_TEXT;
  hdi.pszText = name;
  hdi.cchTextMax = 260;
  SendMessage(hWnd, HDM_GETITEM, i, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hdi));
  std::cout << "  " << i << ") " << hdi.pszText << "\n";
}
```

---

Because we need to store the input and output memory in another program's space, something like this is necessary (please add error checking etc. according to your liking):

```
struct InterProcessData {
  HDITEM hdi;
  TCHAR buffer[260];
};

// Open the owning process and allocate a buffer big enough for
// our inter-process communication
DWORD dwProcessId;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcessId);
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(
  PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE,
  FALSE, dwProcessId);
InterProcessData* pRemoteData = reinterpret_cast<InterProcessData*>(
  VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(InterProcessData), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));

int count = SendMessage(hWnd, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
std::cout << "There are " << count << " items.\n";

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  InterProcessData data;
  data.hdi.mask = HDI_TEXT;
  data.hdi.pszText = pRemoteData->buffer;
  data.hdi.cchTextMax = 260;

  // Write the HDITEM structure to the space in the remote process
  // (without the buffer, its contents are undefined anyway)
  WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteData, &data, sizeof(data.hdi), NULL);

  // Send the message itself, passing the remote address in lParam
  SendMessage(hWnd, HDM_GETITEM, i, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&pRemoteData->hdi));

  // Read the data back, HDITEM and the buffer
  ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteData, &data, sizeof(data), NULL);

  // The documentation says that the pszText can point elsewhere -
  // copy it to our buffer in that case
  if (data.hdi.pszText != pRemoteData->buffer)
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, data.hdi.pszText, data.buffer, data.hdi.cchTextMax * sizeof(TCHAR), NULL);

  std::cout << "  " << i << ") " << data.buffer << "\n";
}

// Cleanup
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteData, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Comment: When I use the code, it compiles perfectly, however when I run the program and it searches program2 for the items, it finds the # of items (15), however when it starts the SendMessage() to get the item text, program2 turns off and it starts outputting something like (pisymbole)TTw% for all the 15 items... Any ideas why that might have happened?

Comment: Ok thanks for all the info bro. I did debug that the program exists out exactly when the code: SendMessage(hWnd, HDM_GETITEM, i, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hdi)); is used. I am guessing for some reason a msg is sent to program2 that causes some kind of error in program2. Any Ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51761/discussion-between-yirkha-and-computerwizard)